# Static library callback

Tags: objective-c, delegates, static-libraries

I have a static library that is currently sending responses using NSNotificationCenter. But I feel like delegates would be a better solution. The problem is how do I call the delegate methods when I do not know their headers yet. Im not sure how to implement the stuff that is not up to me when the library is in use.

So is there a good of allowing the user to create their own methods and the library calling them when they are needed?

Comment: Yes, the delegation pattern is suited exactly for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates are often communicated with by you declaring a protocol which specifies the set of callbacks.

```
@protocol MONImageGeneratorObserver <NSObject>
@required
// called when an image has been generated
- (void)generatedImageWasSavedToURL:(NSURL *)pURL;

- (void)imageGenerationDidComplete;

@end
```

Then you can tell your client the interface they must implement by specifying the protocol in your APIs:

```
- (void)setImageGeneratorObserver:(NSObject<MONImageGeneratorObserver>*)pObserver;
```

---

Another good way to accomplish this is provide a parameter which is a block. You'll usually want to copy that block when you receive it. Then you don't need to know anything about the client's code.

Your API should be very specific:

- that you copy it
- on which thread the block will be performed

---

```
@interface MONObject : NSObject

+ (void)performAsynchronousLoadWithSuccessfulCallback:(void(^)(void))pSuccess errorCallback:(void(^)(NSError *))pError;

@end


@implementation MONObject

+ (void)performAsynchronousLoadWithSuccessfulCallback:(void(^)(void))pSuccess errorCallback:(void(^)(NSError *))pError
{
 if (random()%2) {
  // load succeeded!
  pSuccess();
 }
 else {
  // load failed = =
  NSError * e = ...;
  pError(e);
 }
}

@end
```

In both cases, *you* specify the interface and do not need to see their headers in your implementation. They can call their own methods in the block body or in their definitions of `MONImageGeneratorObserver` callbacks.

Comment: I think the blocks would work quite well with the way I have things now. Can you store a dictionary of blocks to call one at a later point?

Comment: @walsh06 yes, you can. again, you should copy those blocks whenever you would use them 'later' (really simplified). blocks on ios and osx are implemented as objc objects; you can retain and release them, as well as use them as values in `NSDictionary` instances. normally, a complex callback interface would be implemented using a protocol - a dictionary is unusual. if your client's state per callback is complex, then blocks can be used as function objects, which can offer a lot of flexibility to your clients.